# Define a variable of type 'Type' which only accepts types which are subclasses of a specific type

Tags: c#

I'm using C# and I have the following method in my code:

```
public void Test(System.Type type) {...}
```

But I want the variable 'type' to represent a type which must be a subclass of class `MyClass`. Just to be clear, I don't want 'type' itself to be a subclass of `MyClass` because it's supposed to represent a type. For example, the call `Test(typeof(int))` shouldn't be allowed because 'int' is not a subclass of `MyClass`.

Is it possible in C#?

**Update:**
I asked this question after spending a long time trying to find solutions online but turns out it's already been asked before here: [C#: Restricting Types in method parameters (not generic parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885987/c-restricting-types-in-method-parameters-not-generic-parameters) and I missed it. Too bad even the answers in that thread don't seem to solve the problem properly.

**Update 2:**
Turns out (see solution to this question) that instead of passing a parameter to the method, it's possible to use generics and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Use generic arguments?

Comment: And... where is `MyClass`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: It's possible using generics, but not as the question has been specified.

Comment: `Test<T>() where T: MyClass`

Comment: @yyy All types are *not* subclasses of Type.  All types are subclasses of `Object`.

Comment: Amy, you're right. What I meant to write was: "I tried using generics but I can't use 'where T : MyClass' because I don't want T to be a subclass of MyClass. I want it to work like System.Type but only for subclasses of MyClass."

Comment: Note that the class `Type` only describes types but is not otherwise related to these types. In particular, they do not have any inheritance relationship with the describes types (except accidentally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic with constraint for this purpose:

```
public void Test<T>() where T : MyClass
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And how do you pass a parameter to the method Test()?

Comment: @yyy, this is not necessary, `Test` creates the `type` variable itself from the generic type parameter. You would call it like: `Test<MyDerivedClass>();`. It would not be possible to call it with `Test<int>();`, because of the type constraint `where T : MyClass`. But you can only use this method, if you know the type name at compile time.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks Xiaoy312 and Olivier Jacot-Descombes!